# Is there any way to make this function more efficient / short?

Tags: solidity

I have a function that is becoming quite long. The function works just fine in the sense that does exactly what is supposed to, but it does not look great in terms of readability and future mantainance for other devs. Is there any suggestion to make this funciton more short/efficent?

```
mapping(address => AllUserStakedTimestamp) internal allUserStakes;

struct AllUserStakedTimestamp {
    bool[] _wasUnstaked;
    bool[] _autoRenewal;
    uint[] _amountStaked;
    uint[] _timeOfStake;
    uint[] _timesOfRelease;
    uint[] _optionReleaseSelected; // 0-1-2
    uint[] _epochDuration;
    uint[] _rewardPerCycle;
    uint[] _finalStakeReward;
}

function stake(uint _tokens, uint _userReleaseTimeSelection, bool _autoRenewal) public payable returns(bool){
    require(paused == false, "paused");
    require(balanceOf(msg.sender) > 0, "no stakebles");
    require(_tokens <= balanceOf(msg.sender));
    require(stakeFeePriceInWei != 0, "stk fees unassigned");
    // vault.transfer(stakeFeePriceInWei);
    uint epochDuration; // seconds
    uint finalChoice; 
    uint finalReward;
    if(_userReleaseTimeSelection == 0) { 
        epochDuration = 30;
        finalChoice = giveMeNewTime(epochDuration); 
        finalReward = 5;
        allUserStakes[msg.sender]._wasUnstaked.push(false);
        allUserStakes[msg.sender]._autoRenewal.push(_autoRenewal);
        allUserStakes[msg.sender]._amountStaked.push(_tokens);
        allUserStakes[msg.sender]._timeOfStake.push(block.timestamp);
        allUserStakes[msg.sender]._timesOfRelease.push(finalChoice);
        allUserStakes[msg.sender]._optionReleaseSelected.push(_userReleaseTimeSelection);
        allUserStakes[msg.sender]._epochDuration.push(epochDuration);
        allUserStakes[msg.sender]._rewardPerCycle.push(finalReward);
        allUserStakes[msg.sender]._finalStakeReward.push(finalReward);
        burn(msg.sender, _tokens);
        return true;
        }
    else if(_userReleaseTimeSelection == 1) {
        epochDuration = 60;
        finalChoice = giveMeNewTime(epochDuration); 
        finalReward = 10;
        allUserStakes[msg.sender]._wasUnstaked.push(false);
        allUserStakes[msg.sender]._autoRenewal.push(_autoRenewal);
        allUserStakes[msg.sender]._amountStaked.push(_tokens);
        allUserStakes[msg.sender]._timeOfStake.push(block.timestamp);
        allUserStakes[msg.sender]._timesOfRelease.push(finalChoice);
        allUserStakes[msg.sender]._optionReleaseSelected.push(_userReleaseTimeSelection);
        allUserStakes[msg.sender]._epochDuration.push(epochDuration);
        allUserStakes[msg.sender]._rewardPerCycle.push(finalReward);
        allUserStakes[msg.sender]._finalStakeReward.push(finalReward);
        burn(msg.sender, _tokens);
        return true;
        }
    else if(_userReleaseTimeSelection == 2) {
        epochDuration = 90;
        finalChoice = giveMeNewTime(epochDuration); 
        finalReward = 15;
        allUserStakes[msg.sender]._wasUnstaked.push(false);
        allUserStakes[msg.sender]._autoRenewal.push(_autoRenewal);
        allUserStakes[msg.sender]._amountStaked.push(_tokens);
        allUserStakes[msg.sender]._timeOfStake.push(block.timestamp);
        allUserStakes[msg.sender]._timesOfRelease.push(finalChoice);

        allUserStakes[msg.sender]._optionReleaseSelected.push(_userReleaseTimeSelection);
        allUserStakes[msg.sender]._epochDuration.push(epochDuration);
        allUserStakes[msg.sender]._rewardPerCycle.push(finalReward);
        allUserStakes[msg.sender]._finalStakeReward.push(finalReward);    
        burn(msg.sender, _tokens);
        return true;
        }
    else {revert("only 1|2|3");}
    }
```

Any suggestion on how to improve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed some patterns in your code that can certainly be optimized for redability.
Check the refactor:

```js
    uint256 constant BASE_EPOCH_DURATION = 30;
    uint256 constant BASE_FINAL_REWARD = 5;

    mapping(address => AllUserStakedTimestamp) internal allUserStakes;

    struct AllUserStakedTimestamp {
        bool[] _wasUnstaked;
        bool[] _autoRenewal;
        uint[] _amountStaked;
        uint[] _timeOfStake;
        uint[] _timesOfRelease;
        uint[] _optionReleaseSelected; // 0-1-2
        uint[] _epochDuration;
        uint[] _rewardPerCycle;
        uint[] _finalStakeReward;
    }

    modifier allowedUserReleaseTimeSelectionRange(uint _userReleaseTimeSelection) {
        require(
        _userReleaseTimeSelection == 0 ||
        _userReleaseTimeSelection == 2 ||
        _userReleaseTimeSelection == 2, "only 0|1|2");
        _;
    }

    modifier ableToStake(uint256 _tokens) {
        require(paused == false, "paused");
        require(balanceOf(msg.sender) > 0, "no stakebles");
        require(_tokens <= balanceOf(msg.sender));
        require(stakeFeePriceInWei != 0, "stk fees unassigned");
        _;
    }

    function stake(uint _tokens, uint _userReleaseTimeSelection, bool _autoRenewal)
        public
        payable
        allowedUserReleaseTimeSelectionRange(_userReleaseTimeSelection)
        ableToStake(_tokens)
        returns(bool) {

        // vault.transfer(stakeFeePriceInWei);
        // In seconds
        uint256 epochDuration = BASE_EPOCH_DURATION * (_userReleaseTimeSelection + 1);
        uint256 finalChoice = giveMeNewTime(epochDuration);
        uint256 finalReward = BASE_FINAL_REWARD * (_userReleaseTimeSelection + 1);

        // Currently there's no way to optimize multiple mapping read/write because
        // we cannot create a copy of a mapping in memory
        allUserStakes[msg.sender]._wasUnstaked.push(false);
        allUserStakes[msg.sender]._autoRenewal.push(_autoRenewal);
        allUserStakes[msg.sender]._amountStaked.push(_tokens);
        allUserStakes[msg.sender]._timeOfStake.push(block.timestamp);
        allUserStakes[msg.sender]._timesOfRelease.push(finalChoice);
        allUserStakes[msg.sender]._optionReleaseSelected.push(_userReleaseTimeSelection);
        allUserStakes[msg.sender]._epochDuration.push(epochDuration);
        allUserStakes[msg.sender]._rewardPerCycle.push(finalReward);
        allUserStakes[msg.sender]._finalStakeReward.push(finalReward);
        burn(msg.sender, _tokens);
        return true;

    }
```

I created 2 constants BASE_EPOCH_DURATION and BASE_FINAL_REWARD to have the starting point for the epochDuration and finalReward.
If the `_userReleaseTimeSelection` is 0, then 30 * (0 + 1) = 30, what we want in this case.
Also, for final reward starting at 5, then 5 * (0 + 1) = 5.
For `epochDuration` 60 and 90, 30 * (1 + 1) (when `_userReleaseTimeSelection` = 1), then 30 * (2) = 60. For 90, 30 * (2 + 1) => 30 * 3 = 90.
For `finalReward` 10 and 15: 5 * (1 + 1) => 5 * 2 = 10. And 15: 5 * (2 + 1) => 5 * 3 => 15.

Also, I moved some of the requirements checks into a custom modifier.
If you notice, the calculated fields were only `epochDuration`, `finalChoice`, and `finalReward`. All the other assignment were exactly the same, so no need to have them multiple times.

There is no way currently to optimize multiple `mapping`s reads and writes in solidity because we cannot make a copy of a mapping in memory, like we can with arrays.

Or the following version, which points directly to the struct in storage to modify it:

```js
    uint256 constant BASE_EPOCH_DURATION = 30;
    uint256 constant BASE_FINAL_REWARD = 5;

    mapping(address => AllUserStakedTimestamp) internal allUserStakes;

    struct AllUserStakedTimestamp {
        bool[] _wasUnstaked;
        bool[] _autoRenewal;
        uint[] _amountStaked;
        uint[] _timeOfStake;
        uint[] _timesOfRelease;
        uint[] _optionReleaseSelected; // 0-1-2
        uint[] _epochDuration;
        uint[] _rewardPerCycle;
        uint[] _finalStakeReward;
    }

    modifier allowedUserReleaseTimeSelectionRange(uint _userReleaseTimeSelection) {
        require(
        _userReleaseTimeSelection == 0 ||
        _userReleaseTimeSelection == 2 ||
        _userReleaseTimeSelection == 2, "only 0|1|2");
        _;
    }

    modifier ableToStake(uint256 _tokens) {
        require(paused == false, "paused");
        require(balanceOf(msg.sender) > 0, "no stakebles");
        require(_tokens <= balanceOf(msg.sender));
        require(stakeFeePriceInWei != 0, "stk fees unassigned");
        _;
    }

    function stake(uint _tokens, uint _userReleaseTimeSelection, bool _autoRenewal)
        public
        payable
        allowedUserReleaseTimeSelectionRange(_userReleaseTimeSelection)
        ableToStake(_tokens)
        returns(bool) {

        // vault.transfer(stakeFeePriceInWei);
        // In seconds
        uint256 epochDuration = BASE_EPOCH_DURATION * (_userReleaseTimeSelection + 1);
        uint256 finalChoice = giveMeNewTime(epochDuration);
        uint256 finalReward = BASE_FINAL_REWARD * (_userReleaseTimeSelection + 1);

        // We can point to the struct directly and modify it.
        // We are only going to access the arrays in the struct only once for each of them,
        // so we don't need to copy them them to memory (coping them to memory would help anyways, because we wouldn't be able to use the `.push` method in memory arrays).
        // We point to the struct directly because doing `allUserStakes[msg.sender]` many times is more expensive because 
        // the EVM has to calculate the `keccak256` hash of the `msg.sender` along with the mapping index in storage every time.
        AllUserStakedTimestamp storage allUserStakedTimestamp = allUserStakes[msg.sender];

        allUserStakedTimestamp._wasUnstaked.push(false);
        allUserStakedTimestamp._autoRenewal.push(_autoRenewal);
        allUserStakedTimestamp._amountStaked.push(_tokens);
        allUserStakedTimestamp._timeOfStake.push(block.timestamp);
        allUserStakedTimestamp._timesOfRelease.push(finalChoice);
        allUserStakedTimestamp._optionReleaseSelected.push(_userReleaseTimeSelection);
        allUserStakedTimestamp._epochDuration.push(epochDuration);
        allUserStakedTimestamp._rewardPerCycle.push(finalReward);
        allUserStakedTimestamp._finalStakeReward.push(finalReward);
        burn(msg.sender, _tokens);
        return true;

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can save a bunch of lines by populating your struct this way:

```
AllUserStakedTimestamp memory allUserStakes  = allUserStakes{false,_autoRenewal,_tokens...}
```